# 2002 Toyota Camry driver's side power seat one side stuck

Tags: toyota, camry, seat

I have an issue with my driver's side power seat. The side closest to the center console is stuck all the way back but the left side works just fine.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Took the seat out of the car to get better views of entire mechanisms.
- Uninstalled and reinstalled threaded axles connecting front motor to rails.
- Switched axles
- Manually used square drive to move stuck side w/ no movement in the rail (other sides works fine)

  - Did this with full axle connection and without connection same results
- Rubber mallet to the back of the rail

My guesses are that there's something inside the railing that I can't see that might be causing the issue or the entire assembly on the stuck side is stripped somehow and it has lost all grip to the threaded axle running inside the railing.

Any advice? I'm in no way a mechanic by the way -- just a 5' college student trying to save money and fix her car during quarantine!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the gear near the front of the seat is not working properly. You mentioned "Manually used square drive to move stuck side w/ no movement in the rail (other sides works fine)". My experience is that this part is only available from a junk yard.